# How should I make my answers more useful?

Tags: discussion, answers, quality-improvement

I just received my unsung-hero badge  and I checked my answers and found indeed there have been plenty of 0-scored accepted ones. I do answer in a very high-traffic zone i.e in [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and the reason of getting this badge could be answering the low-rep questioners who do not have sufficient reps to up-vote.

I started contributing here actively since only about 2 months ago and I'm just wondering if I might be missing some nuances as to how to make useful answers.

So should I try making my answers perhaps more elaborate so as to others to find them useful and upvote? Or shall I just relax and accept the fact that as a new contributor I should wait and gain sufficient reps until the community starts trusting my answers to up-vote?

Comment: The JavaScript tag is tough. The majority of my answers are there. Also, the majority of my answers have 1 or less score (not counting accepted answers). Plenty are at zero and not accepted, either - I just haven't checked the ratio.

Comment: simply wait. 2 months is still too early to get plenty of upvotes. Most of the upvotes come later

Comment: A lot of questions in [tag:javascript] are dupes, and not the "useful signpost" kind but the "OP didn't bother to look" kind (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62550688/3001761). That means even if your answer gets upvotes, the question will likely be closed and deleted, and even if it's not deleted most users will end up on the canonical dupe target and won't see your answer. The solution is to focus your time on high quality questions that might stick around, to access the long tail of value and upvotes @TemaniAfif mentions - look for dupes *before* answering.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I see that. I'm just curious, I see a lot of dupes not being reported as such. What should be done in that case? Even If I vote to close, that'd require 2 more votes. And as the question gets older that do not get sufficient attention I think

Comment: Vote to close anyway. The OP can accept the dupe, then it doesn't even take three votes. Voting puts it in the close queue however old it is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I will. But I'm still not sure if they get sufficient attention, A case in point is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62443481/how-to-display-a-variable-value-aling-with-the-text-in-html, I guess this'd have been asked hundreds of time but still didn't get caught even after 8-days. I just reported now. Still the chances that it'd be closed is slim because of lack of attention due to its age. I'm not sure when we take some action like 'voting to close', does a question becomes active so that others could see it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, if you want upvotes, you should make sure the Q&A pair provides long-term value.

Some simple steps can help with that:

For the answer:

- Make sure it's clear what the actual problem was (don't provide just a solution)
- Provide a solution that's both understandable, and generalizable to others experiencing the same error
- Make sure to explain the solution, so others understand how the problem was solved

For the question:

- Make sure the question is unique, and not a duplicate
- Make sure the question is findable to others searching for the same problem
- Make sure the question is useful to others, so not highly localized (previously, we had a close reason for too localized questions)

Often, this will mean you have to edit question. It's great you have >2K rep, so you can do this without requiring their approval. You often have to rewrite questions with titles like *why can't I send mail to my clients* to something that will help others experiencing the same problem find it (something like *how to solve Bar error when sending mail with Foo*), and add appropriate tags.

If a question is not findable, or is a duplicate, your answer provides no value to anyone but the person asking it, so it will be hard to get upvotes. Quite often, the question is more important for upvotes on the answer than the answer itself. But luckily, you're free to improve the question, and should not hesitate to rewrite it to make it more generalizable and findable.

Another factor for upvotes on answers unfortunately is the rep of the person asking the question. If it's below the rep required to upvote, you can be sure the one asking is not going to upvote your answer. But this shouldn't be an important consideration when answering questions.